# Does This Proof Make Sense?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I've been working on understanding the following proof for some time: [Link](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Endomorphism_sends_more_than_three-fourths_of_elements_to_squares_implies_abelian)

Can somebody please tell me if my solution makes sense (and, in some places, help me patch up the proof)?

We want to prove that if we have a group, $G$, and endomorphism, $\phi$ such that the subset of elements, $x \in G$ satisfying $\phi(x) = x^2$, makes up more than $\frac{3}{4}$ of the elements of $G$, then $G$ is abelian and $\phi(x) = x^2$ for all $x\in G$.

To begin, let $S$ be the subset of $G$ where any element, $x$, in $S$ satisfies $\phi(x) = x^2$

Now, let $x, y, xy$ be elements that are all in $S$. We claim that then, $xy = yx$. This follows naturally from the definition of homomorphism. We must have $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y).$ Since $x, y, xy \in S$, it means $$(xy)^2 = x^2 y^2.$$

**I don't understand how to prove from here that xy = yx.**

Then, denote $x^{-1}S$ as the set of elements: $\{x^{-1}s, s \in S \}.$ Each element in $x^{-1}S$ corresponds to the inverse of some element in $S.$ That means they both have the same number of elements. Furthermore, by the Principles of Inclusion and Exclusion, we have the following statement: $$|S \cup x^{-1}S| + |S \cap x^{-1}S| = |S| + |x^{-1}S|.$$

Because we know that $|S| = |x^{-1}S| > \frac{3}{4} |G|$, $$|S \cup x^{-1}S| + |S \cap x^{-1}S| > 1.5 |G|.$$

Additionally, $|S \cup x^{-1}S| \le |G|.$ The elements in $x^{-1}S$ correspond to the inverses of the elements in $S$. By the definition of groups, $G$ must contain all of the inverses of its elements. Hence, it contains the inverses of $S$. This means that all elements in $|S \cup x^{-1}S|$ are contained in $G \rightarrow |S \cup x^{-1}S| < |G|.$

Taking that into account, we then get $$|S \cap x^{-1}S| > 0.5 |G|.$$

Now, let $y \in S \cap x^{-1}S.$ Notice that $y \in S, S \cap x^{-1}S.$

Because $y$ is an element in $x^{-1}S$, there must exist an $s \in S$ such that $y = x^{-1}s.$

Rearrangement gives $xy = s$ which means all three of $x, y,$ and $xy$ are all in $S$. We proved above that when this happens, $xy = yx.$ That means that $y \in C_G(x)$ where $C_G(x)$ is the centralizer of the element $x$ in group $G$.

Because $y$ is just some generic element in $S \cap x^{-1}S$ and we showed that it is in the centralizer of $x$, it follows that $S \cap x^{-1}S \subseteq C_G(x).$

However, earlier we showed that $|S \cap x^{-1}S| > 0.5 |G|.$ This means that $$|C_G(x)| > 0.5 |G|.$$

The centralizer is a subgroup of $S$. Since it is at least half as big as $G$, it must be $G$. Thus, $C_G(x) = G.$

Because this statement holds for all $x \in S$, it follows that $S \subseteq Z(G).$

But, we know that $|S| > \frac{3}{4} |G|.$ Because $S \subseteq Z(G),$ $$|Z(G)| > \frac{3}{4} |G|.$$

$Z(G)$ is also a subgroup of $S$ and because it contains more than half of the elements in $G$, it also must equal $G$. Thus, $Z(G) = G.$

By the definition of abelian groups, a group is abelian iff $G = Z(G)$. We just showed that which means $G$ is abelian.

Now, consider the subgroup $\langle S \rangle$ made by the elements of $S.$ Because $|S| > \frac{1}{2} G,$ $| \langle S \rangle | > \frac{1}{2} |G| \rightarrow \langle S \rangle = G.$

By definition, $S$ must be a generating set of $G$.

Because $G$ is abelian, there must exist an endomorphism, $\tau$ that maps each element to its square. Realize that $\tau$ and $\phi$ behave the same over the elements in $S$. Since we just showed that $S$ is a generating set of $G$, and an endomorphism's behavior over a generating set uniquely defines it, $\tau$ and $\phi$ must be the same. This implies that $S$ maps every element to its square, as desired.

1. Does my solution make sense?
2. Can somebody help me patch up the part about $xy = yx$?
3. Did I understand/use the $x^{-1}S$ thing correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$, multiply on the left by $x^{-1}$ and on the right by $y^{-1}$ to get $yx=xy$.

I don’t understand what you mean by the statement that each element of $x^{-1}S$ corresponds to the inverse of some element of $S$. $|x^{-1}S|=|S|$ because the map $S\to x^{-1}S:s\mapsto x^{-1}s$ is a bijection.

I don’t understand the paragraph that begins *Additionally*, and it is in any case unnecessary. You know that

$$|S\cup x^{-1}S|+|S\cap x^{-1}S|>\frac32|G|\tag{1}$$

and

$$|S\cup x^{-1}S|\le|G|\,,\tag{2}$$

and subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ immediately gives you

$$|S\cap x^{-1}S|>\frac12|G|\,.$$

For the next step in the argument you should explicitly state that $x\in S$, since you need that assumption to draw the conclusion that $xy=yx$. The rest appears to be okay.

Comment: @delhimaths: Multiplying $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$ on the left by $x^{-1}$ results in $yxy=xy^2$, since $(xy)^2=xyxy$. Multiplying that on the right by $y^{-1}$ then yields $yx=xy$. I am of course multiplying **both sides** of the equation by $x^{-1}$ on the left and $y^{-1}$ on the right.

Comment: @delhimaths: A map is simply a function. In this case it’s a function from $S$ to $x^{-1}S$, as indicated by the notation $S\to x^{-1}S$, and it is specifically the function that sends an element $s\in S$ to the element $x^{-1}s\in x^{-1}S$, as indicated by the notation $s\mapsto x^{-1}s$. (These notations are not peculiar to group theory: they’re common throughout mathematics.)

Comment: @delhimaths: The two things that I said that I didn’t understand are at least unclear and quite possibly incorrect, but they’re also unnecessary and can be replaced by the correct arguments that I mentioned. The rest will be okay if you simply note that you’re talking about $x\in S$ when you start the argument leading to the conclusion that $S\cap x^{-1}S\subseteq C_G(x)$.